# Eyedropper tool not clickable in android studio

Tags: android-studio

After the new update of Android studio , the eyedropper tool is not clickable for some reason .

[image]

any ideas why its not happening

Comment: Just checked and yes, it's not working. Though I never tried it before.

Comment: Yes,so strange right ?

Comment: So when checking, I clicked it so many times but it didn't work, I switched to chrome and replied to you, but after sometimes when I switched back to Android studio, the cursor was eyedropper tool which didn't let me select anything which didn't even cancel out even when the color switcher window in above pic was closed. I tried everything, but nothing changed the cursor back to normal, I had to quit the studio by pressing Alt+f4. Obviously, a bug.

Comment: Which android version are you using?